# General formula for this sum $\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{7+2(-\frac{1}{2})^i}{3}$ and strong induction

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, power-series

I need help to figure out the general formula of this sum:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{7+2(-\frac{1}{2})^i}{3}$$

Then prove it with strong induction.

Comment: Where is the summation index under $\sum$? I guess some typo?

Comment: I just edited (-1/2)^i

Comment: OK, and now You are looking for a closed form. What have You tried?

Comment: I tried to factor the 1/3 and get the sum of 7 + the 2 * sum of (-1/2)^i since it is a geometric series.
But I didn't get the right sum. I am not sure what to do

Comment: Ok, You might include this in Your question.( see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)).This doesn't work since $\sum_{i=0}^{n}(-\frac{1}{2})^i$ isn't a geometric series, because of the negative sign. This is probably why you didn't get the right sum

Answer (score 4):

Here's a start.
It's usually good
to split a complicated problem
into simpler parts.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{7+2(-\frac{1}{2})^i}{3}
&=\frac13\sum_{i=0}^n (7+2(-\frac{1}{2})^i)\\
&=\frac13\left(\sum_{i=0}^n 7+\sum_{i=0}^n2(-\frac{1}{2})^i)\right)\\
&=\frac13\left(7(n+1)+2\sum_{i=0}^n(-\frac{1}{2})^i)\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Your turn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have added it in with the question.
That's exactly where I got. For the (-1/2)^2 I thought it was a geometric series maybe that was the problem.

Comment: @MohamedTa And now you might try something like $\sum_{i=0}^n(-\frac{1}{2})^i=\sum_{i=0}^{ \frac{n}{2}}(-\frac{1}{2})^{2i}+\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{n}{2}-1}(-\frac{1}{2})^{2i+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{ \frac{n}{2}}(\frac{1}{4})^{i}-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{ \frac{n}{2}-1}(\frac{1}{4})^{i}$ for even $n$ and then use the geometric series idea.